# Angle between velocity and acceleration for projectile motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

Suppose I have a projectile and launch it with an oblique velocity, meaning it has both horizontal and vertical components of velocity.
Neglecting air resistance and the like, it’s trajectory should look like what I drew-
[image]

Here the red arrow is the downward constant acceleration, the green arrow is the net velocity (vector sum of its components) and the angle between the acceleration and velocity I have marked in yellow.

I have filled in the angle in the regions where I think the angle between the velocity and the acceleration would be acute, which I think is the entirety of the projectile motion after it crosses its maximum height till it reaches the ground again.

However, on searching the net and also from a question paper I saw, it states the the angle between velocity and acceleration is    **minimum and acute** at **only one point.**

Why is it only one point? Does the ‘minimum’ word have anything to do with it? I thought the angle would be acute over a number of points in the second half of the projectile’s motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle will be **acute** for whole second half of the projectile motion but will be **minimum and acute** ( both same time) at the point where ball just strikes the ground.

It will be **maximum and obtuse** just as you launch the ball.

Note that angles which are  **minimum and obtuse**  and **maximum and acute** does not exist.

Comment: Thanks. But then according to that definition, won’t the minimum and obtuse and maximum and acute angle both be just before and after the maximum height point of the projectile? (Since at $H_{max}$ angle between velocity and acceleration is 90)

Comment: @Metaxylene Yes but suppose the angle in the second half (in degrees) is 89, then before that 89.9 would have been there, then before that 89.99 would have been there and even before that 89.999 would have been and there and even before......

Comment: So we cannot give maximum value to any angle since there always exist an angle greater than that

Comment: yeh you can say dat... like jus get the feel of it....

Comment: So what you mean is that it’s possible, but it’s just too small and varies continuously?

Comment: @Metaxylene We cannot provide definite value, if you say it's 89, then I will say no it will be 89.99 and we can continue discussing this for our lifetime but we will not end at at certain definite value since there exists no number which is just greater than 90

Comment: Since this whole question is theoretical, I was assuming a theoretically defined very small instant of time after the maximum height. But I understand your point, that point of time can keep getting smaller and smaller. Thanks

Comment: @Metaxylene Yes exactly